# "Forwarding" string literals

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, string-literals

I am dealing with a library that has a variadic macro meant to be used like printf

```
#define PRINTF_LIKE (FORMAT, ...) //Some statement expression
```

Since `PRINTF_LIKE` was required to evaluate to something, and in order avoid the usual `if` and dangling `else` issue with macros having multiple statements, it was implemented using [gcc's statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). However, I need my code to build with the intel compiler, which doesn't allow [destructible entities inside a statement expression](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1487). This means I can't write code like this:

```
PRINTF_LIKE("%s", getString().c_str());
```

where `getString` returns an `std::string`. To work around this, I have a simple variadic template wrapper.

```
template <typename ... Rest>
int callPrintfLike(const char* const format, Rest... rest)
{
 return PRINTF_LIKE(format, rest...);//warning: format string is not a string literal [-Wformat-nonliteral]
}
```

And use it like this:

```
callPrintfLike("%s", getString().c_str());//warning as shown in the above comment
```

This trips up clang and gcc's `-Wformat-nonliteral` warning. Is there a way for me to somehow "forward" string-literalness and have this warning be triggered only when callPrintfLike is not called with a string literal?

EDIT : One of the answers below suggested using `__attribute__((format))`. However, [that doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbb7f942e59b6128) since the `format` attribute needs a variadic function.

Comment: I can't quite get why you can't write code like PRINTF_LIKE("%s", getString().c_str());

Comment: A variadic template that wraps a macro. Now I have seen everything. (NOTE: actually variadic templates were introduced to evade unsafe macros and printf)

Comment: Is the reason that you can't use `getString().c_str()` that `PRINTF_LIKE` expands to a statement expression that assigns the argument to a variable and even before that variable can be used, the temporary `std::string` is destructed again leaving a dangling pointer?

Comment: Is this library your own or perhaps managed by you? It seems an awful lot like it would be better to just remove that `PRINTF_LIKE` macro, if possible, instead of working around its deficiencies.

Comment: @juhist The issue is because I also need my code to build with the intel compiler and they don't support destructible entities inside the statement expression. Edited the question.

Comment: @5gon12eder The intel compiler disallows it. Edited the question.

Comment: @hvd Sadly, I don't have control over it. I would love to throw an [SEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem) field over it :)

Comment: C++14 by any chance?  In particular, does `auto x=[](auto&&...){};` compile on all targets?  Clearly C++11 support.  (can you check that expression?  Some compilers implemented it early)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked around it by turning warnings off for the function, but providing another macro to call it through and re-enabling those warnings here through a dead-branch of the ternary operator.

```
//Compiler specific pragmas to turn off the -Wformat-security and -Wformat-literal warnings go here

template <typename ... Rest>
int callPrintfLike(const char* const format, Rest... rest)
{
 return PRINTF_LIKE(format, rest...);
}

//Pop diagnostic pragmas

#define NEW_PRINTF_LIKE (FORMAT, ...) (true ? callPrintfLike(FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__) : printf(FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__))
```

In `NEW_PRINTF_LIKE`, `printf(FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__)` will never get executed. However, the compile-time checking of the `printf` call and warnings about non-literal `FORMAT` and arguments not matching the format string will still be enabled.