# Passing zero argument pack to printf

Tags: c++, gcc, variadic

I have created a class which has a variadic template method. This method calls `printf` function. When passing zero arguments to the method, I get a compile warning by gcc saying:

> warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

A simplified class example is:

```
class printer{
    std::map<int,std::string> str;
  public:
    printer(){
      str[0] = "null\n";
      str[1] = "%4d\n";
      str[2] = "%4d %4d\n";
      str[3] = "%4d %4d\n%4d\n";
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    void print(Args... args){
      printf(str[sizeof...(args)].c_str(),args...);
    }
};
```

When using

```
printer p;
p.print(23);
p.print(345,23);
```

everything compiles smoothly, but when using

```
printer p;
p.print();
```

I get the compile warning

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void printer::print(Args ...) [with Args = {}]’:
main.cpp:23:11:   required from here
main.cpp:17:50: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
       printf(str[sizeof...(args)].c_str(),args...);
```

Of course if I just call

```
printf("null\n");
```

no warning appears.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Can I remove warning without disabling the `-Wformat-security` flag?

Comment: I had asked an almost identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176591/forwarding-string-literals). Not marking this as a dupe since I am not sure if you would be ok with using a macro like in the solution I suggest. If it works, please dupe it.

Comment: Does C++ have `printf` now? You're calling C `printf`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala There's `std::printf`... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an expected warning, if we look at the document for [-Wformat-security](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat_002dsecurity-207) it says:

> -Wformat-security
>       If -Wformat is specified, also warn about uses of format functions that represent possible security problems. At present, **this warns about calls to printf and scanf functions where the format string is not a string literal and there are no format arguments, as in printf (foo);**. This may be a security hole if the format string came from untrusted input and contains `%n'. (This is currently a subset of what -Wformat-nonliteral warns about, but in future warnings may be added to -Wformat-security that are not included in -Wformat-nonliteral.)
>   -Wformat=2

which is the case when you pass no arguments since the result of `c_str()` is not a *string literal*.

This case:

```
printf("null\n");
```

does not warn because `"null\n"` is a string literal not possibly input from a user.

We can see why this is a potential security issue from this [%n format specifier program giving different outputs on different compilers. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29218872/1708801).

It looks like you have to turn on specific switches if you don't want all of `-Wformat-secrity`:

> -Wformat is included in -Wall. For more control over some aspects of format checking, the options -Wformat-y2k, -Wno-format-extra-args, -Wno-format-zero-length, -Wformat-nonliteral, -Wformat-security, and -Wformat=2 are available, but are not included in -Wall.

Although this is poor option if `-Wformat-secrity` adds more options later on, then you need to continually keep updating.

Another alternative as AndyG mentioned would be an overload:

```
void print(){
  std::printf("null\n");
}
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to overload OP's `print` function to one that takes no arguments (a "do nothing" function)?

Comment: What I don't get is: Why the no-literal warning appears only the zero argument case and not in the other cases?

Comment: @ctheo see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218954/1708801) for an example of why the no argument case is a problem.

Comment: @AndyG yes, I meant to add that, had to step away.

Comment: Thanks @ShafikYaghmour. So, avoiding warning can be done by `-Wformat-nonliteral` option. The challenge now is how to really protect the software from formating attacks. Maybe I will post an other question later.

Comment: @ctheo the overload method seems like a better method since you don't have to adjust your warning flags.